# What is the difference between Method, Property and Variable in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I'm learning OOP in PHP and Laravel. So far my idea is that `variable` and `property` are more or less the same. `Methods` are equivalent to `functions`. But sometimes I see in many articles that they represent `variable` and `property` slightly differently. For example in [laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions), **Model property** and **variable** have different terminologies. What are the differences (if any) between `variable` and `property`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, method is a function.

Model property would be a global variable within the class, so you can use it in all the methods. And depending on the access modifier (private, protected, public) the model property can be used from other classes inheriting/instantiating from that class.

While a variable will be something used within a method and has usage only within the body of that method.

Comment: And global variables ? can't be use outside the method ?

Comment: Please open a new question with an example on what you are trying to achieve to get a better answer.
Global variable outside of method can be used, but only to add or default the value to another variable / property.

Answer (score 1):

A property is an variable that belongs to the object. The are also called "Members". Imho the main Difference is the Scope. A variable is only available within the method but a property in the whole Class and also in the object if you use public as visibility. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score -1):

A property (also called a member variable) in PHP OOP is a variable that exists inside of a class, and must be private, protected, or public. For example:

```
class Bird {
    private $color; // This is a property of the Bird class
}

$var = 123; // This is just a normal variable
```

So the **Model Property** that the documentation is referring to is just a member variable of the model.

As far as the difference between functions and methods, they are similar except for 1 major difference: methods are functions that exist inside of a class, and must be private, protected, or public. For example:

```
class Bird {
    public function sing() { // This is a method
        echo 'tweet-tweet';
    }
}

function sayHello() { // This is a function
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Note: If you do not declare a property or method as private, protected, or public, it is assumed that it is public